# Clean code to printf size_t in C++ (or: Nearest equivalent of C99's %z in C++)

Tags: c++, printf, size-t

I have some C++ code that prints a `size_t`:

```
size_t a;
printf("%lu", a);
```

I'd like this to compile without warnings on both 32- and 64-bit architectures.

If this were C99, I could use `printf("%z", a);`.  But AFAICT `%z` doesn't exist in any standard C++ dialect.  So instead, I have to do

```
printf("%lu", (unsigned long) a);
```

which is really ugly.

If there's no facility for printing `size_t`s built into the language, I wonder if it's possible to write a printf wrapper or somesuch such that will insert the appropriate casts on `size_t`s so as to eliminate spurious compiler warnings while still maintaining the good ones.

Any ideas?

---

*Edit* To clarify why I'm using printf: I have a relatively large code base that I'm cleaning up.  It uses printf wrappers to do things like "write a warning, log it to a file, and possibly exit the code with an error".  I might be able to muster up enough C++-foo to do this with a cout wrapper, but I'd rather not change every warn() call in the program just to get rid of some compiler warnings.

Comment: Why are you using printf at all should be the question.

Comment: does your compiler inspect the printf string and type check for you?

Comment: My compiler does indeed inspect the printf format string and type check it for me.  I'd like to keep this feature turned on.

Comment: %zu, z is a width specifier not type specifier.  It works for the c printf that you can use seamlessly from C++.  I've commented on it below, so vote for it ;)

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, can't you just use `"%l"`?  Won't that always be the right size?  Or does portability matter?

Comment: C casts are ugly. You could use the constructor syntax like `int(a)` if you had an appropriate `typedef`.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Most compilers have their own specifier for `size_t` and `ptrdiff_t` arguments, Visual C++ for instance use %Iu and %Id respectively, I think that gcc will allow you to use %zu and %zd.

You could create a macro:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__MINGW32__) //__MINGW32__ should goes before __GNUC__
  #define JL_SIZE_T_SPECIFIER    "%Iu"
  #define JL_SSIZE_T_SPECIFIER   "%Id"
  #define JL_PTRDIFF_T_SPECIFIER "%Id"
#elif defined(__GNUC__)
  #define JL_SIZE_T_SPECIFIER    "%zu"
  #define JL_SSIZE_T_SPECIFIER   "%zd"
  #define JL_PTRDIFF_T_SPECIFIER "%zd"
#else
  // TODO figure out which to use.
  #if NUMBITS == 32
    #define JL_SIZE_T_SPECIFIER    something_unsigned
    #define JL_SSIZE_T_SPECIFIER   something_signed
    #define JL_PTRDIFF_T_SPECIFIER something_signed
  #else
    #define JL_SIZE_T_SPECIFIER    something_bigger_unsigned
    #define JL_SSIZE_T_SPECIFIER   something_bigger_signed
    #define JL_PTRDIFF_T_SPECIFIER something-bigger_signed
  #endif
#endif
```

Usage:

```
size_t a;
printf(JL_SIZE_T_SPECIFIER, a);
printf("The size of a is " JL_SIZE_T_SPECIFIER " bytes", a);
```

Comment: It is not that easy. Whether `%z` is supported or not depends on the runtime, not the compiler. Using `__GNUC__` is therefore a bit of a problem, if you mix GCC/mingw with msvcrt (and without using mingw's augmented printf).

Answer (score 77):

The `printf` format specifier `%zu` will work fine on C++ systems; there is no need to make it more complicated.

Comment: @ChrisMarkle A quick test shows me it doesn't work in MinGW. Also the MS site doesn't list it (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). I suppose the answer is no.

Answer (score 24):

**C++11**

C++11 imports C99 so `std::printf` should support the C99 `%zu` format specifier.

**C++98**

On most platforms, `size_t` and `uintptr_t` are equivalent, in which case you can use the [`PRIuPTR`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) macro defined in `<cinttypes>`:

```
size_t a = 42;
printf("If the answer is %" PRIuPTR " then what is the question?\n", a);
```

If you *really* want to be safe, cast to `uintmax_t` and use `PRIuMAX`:

```
printf("If the answer is %" PRIuMAX " then what is the question?\n", static_cast<uintmax_t>(a));
```

Answer (score 16):

On windows and the Visual Studio implementation of printf

```
 %Iu
```

works for me. 
see 
[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcxf1dw6%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. Works in `VS 2008` too. Also keep in mind that one can use `%Id`, `%Ix`and `%IX` too.

Answer (score 12):

Since you're using C++, why not use IOStreams? That should compile without warnings and do the right type-aware thing, as long as you're not using a brain-dead C++ implementation that doesn't define an `operator <<` for `size_t`.

When the actual output has to be done with `printf()`, you can still combine it with IOStreams to get type-safe behavior:

```
size_t foo = bar;
ostringstream os;
os << foo;
printf("%s", os.str().c_str());
```

It's not super-efficient, but your case above deals with file I/O, so that's your bottleneck, not this string formatting code.

Comment: I know that Google forbids the use of cout in their code. Perhaps Justin L. is working under such a restriction.

Comment: In my case (see edit above), an interesting idea might be to try and implement the warn() function in terms of cout.  But that would involve parsing format strings manually, which is...tricky.  :)

Comment: Your latest edit is actually the opposite of what I think might work for me.  I don't want to rewrite all of the code which invokes a printf wrapper, but I wouldn't mind rewriting the implementation of the printf wrapper to use cout.  But I don't think that's going to happen.  :)

Comment: Use `std::stringstream` instead of IO streams.

Comment: Streams have awkward notation. Compare: `printf("x=%i, y=%i;\n", x, y);` vs `cout << "x=" << x << ", y=" << y << ";" << std::endl;`.

Comment: @wonder.mice you can write a variadic-template wrapper which would take arguments separated by commas, it it makes it more readable for you. This will also save you from some headaches with operator precedence. See [an example](http://ideone.com/WQHi8o). In any case this is much more robust than relying on types defined in a format string.

Comment: @Ruslan Checkout https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt for a better alternative. Also modern compilers check types defined in format string, so no problems there.

Comment: @wonder.mice I wouldn't call runtime detection of errors in format string "better". Yes, that library may have some merits, but such errors can and should be detected at compile time, as is with iostream. Exceptions or whatever — it's just a crutch.

Answer (score 9):

The [fmt library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt) provides a fast portable (and safe) implementation of `printf` including the `z` modifier for `size_t`:

```
#include "fmt/printf.h"

size_t a = 42;

int main() {
  fmt::printf("%zu", a);
}
```

In addition to that it supports Python-like format string syntax and captures type information so that you don't have to provide it manually:

```
fmt::print("{}", a);
```

It has been tested with major compilers and provides consistent output across platforms.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of this library.

Comment: and is this now in C++20/23?

Comment: @underscore_d, `std::format` is in C++20 but not `print` unfortunately.

Answer (score 7):

here's a possible solution, but it's not quite a pretty one..

```
template< class T >
struct GetPrintfID
{
  static const char* id;
};

template< class T >
const char* GetPrintfID< T >::id = "%u";


template<>
struct GetPrintfID< unsigned long long > //or whatever the 64bit unsigned is called..
{
  static const char* id;
};

const char* GetPrintfID< unsigned long long >::id = "%lu";

//should be repeated for any type size_t can ever have


printf( GetPrintfID< size_t >::id, sizeof( x ) );
```

Comment: Well...that does achieve my goal of safety and no warnings.  But...yeesh.  I'll take the warnings if that's what I have to do.  :)

Comment: Not pretty?! Depends on taste. It allows to fully portable use of printf with beasts like uintptr_t and alike. Great!

Comment: @user877329 you could build that format string as an std::string and then append GetPrintfID< size_t >::id at the place you need it

Comment: @stijn In other words: no compile-time concatenation availible

Comment: @user877329 no (unless using macros, or I'm missing something). But why would that be a hard requirement?

Answer (score 3):

The effective type underlying **size_t is implementation dependent**.  C Standard defines it as the type returned by the sizeof operator; aside from being unsigned and a sort of integral type, the size_t can be pretty much anything which size can accommodate the biggest value expected to be returned by sizeof().

Consequently the format string to be used for a size_t may vary depending on the server.  It should always have the "u", but may be l or d or maybe something else...

A trick could be to cast it to the biggest integral type on the machine, ensuring no loss in the conversion, and then using the format string associated with this known type.

Comment: I would be cool casting my `size_t`s to the largest integral type on the machine and using the format string associated with this type.  My question is: Is there a way I can do this while maintaining clean code (warnings only for legitimate printf format string errors, no ugly casts, etc.)?  I could write a wrapper which changes the format string, but then GCC wouldn't be able to give me warnings when I legitimately messed up my format string.

Comment: Use CPP macros to test for the size of types; go for the one that matches and specify the format string that goes with the matching type.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <type_traits>

namespace my{
    template<typename ty>
    auto get_string(ty&& arg){
        using rty=typename::std::decay_t<::std::add_const_t<ty>>;
        if constexpr(::std::is_same_v<char, rty>)
            return ::std::string{1,arg};
        else if constexpr(::std::is_same_v<bool, rty>)
            return ::std::string(arg?"true":"false");
        else if constexpr(::std::is_same_v<char const*, rty>)
            return ::std::string{arg};
        else if constexpr(::std::is_same_v<::std::string, rty>)
            return ::std::forward<ty&&>(arg);
        else
            return ::std::to_string(arg);
    };

    template<typename T1, typename ... Args>
    auto printf(T1&& a1, Args&&...arg){
        auto str{(get_string(a1)+ ... + get_string(arg))};
        return ::std::printf(str.c_str());
    };
};
```

Later in code:

```
my::printf("test ", 1, '\t', 2.0);
```