# Is this syntactically correct?

Tags: c

I have code in one of the source file as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int a ;
int b = 256 ;
int c = 16 ;
int d = 4 ;

int main() {

    if ((d <= (b) && (d == ( c / sizeof(a))))
    {
        printf("%d",sizeof(a) );
    }
    return 0;

}
```

I have removed the casts and have simplified on the data names. The `sizeof(a)` can be taken as 4. I want to know if the the `if` syntax is a valid one and if so why doesn't it execute?

PS : I haven't sat down on this for long due to time constraints. Pardon me if you find a childish error in the code.

Comment: I don't know C, but are all those parenthesis really necessary in your if statement?

Comment: Try doing the basic due diligence of parsing that expression and its obviously absurd parenthesization yourself instead of running to SO.

Comment: @pb2q A close paren is missing *somewhere*, but probably not at the end.

Comment: Please don't change your code when there are already answer about the code.

Comment: Sigh. Now the OP has edited the expression to remove a paren. If I could give this question a dozen more downvotes I would.

Comment: @JimBalter : You sneaky mouse ! btw I was on holidays !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to compile it?

Your if statement needs one more ) . That or simplify it to:

```
if ((d <= b) && (d == c / sizeof(a)))
```

Your printf statement should use "%zu\n" for C99, although [it's complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546789/clean-code-to-printf-size-t-in-c-or-nearest-equivalent-of-c99s-z-in-c).

Comment: The correct format to print a `size_t` is `%zu`.

Comment: That's true for C99 at least, so I updated my answer, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One closing bracket is missing IMO. I opended up your if with vertical parantheses alignment technique.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int a ;
int b = 256 ;
int c = 16 ;
int d = 4 ;

int main() {

    if (
        (
         d <= (b) && (
                      d == (
                             c / sizeof(a)
                           )
                     )
        )
       //Here needs another closing parantheses
    {
        printf("%d",sizeof(a) );
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Actually you can sefely remove some parantheses here in your snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a newline to your `printf` statement:

```
printf("%d\n", sizeof a);
```

Standard output is usually buffered, so output doesn't always show up on your console immediately unless there's a newline or you add a `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf` call.

Answer (score 1):

```
((d <= (b) && (d == ( c / sizeof(a))))
```

Looks an extra `(` before the `b`.

```
( (d <= b) && (d == (c/sizeof(a))))
```

Comment: As my comment under OP are all those parenthesis really needed. (I'm not a C guy). It looks like bad mistakes going to happen to me (which is proven by OP).

Comment: @PeeHaa None of the inner parens are needed. Some people (not me) think the ones around the relational operators are good practice.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten closing one paranthesis in line 11 you have opened six and closed five.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an issue with your if statement, it should look like this

```
if ( (d <= b) && (d == ( c / sizeof(a))))
```

you had an extra ( on the left side of the 'b'