# sscanf and fprintf not consistent?

Tags: c++, c

I am creating a file with a header in the following format

```
file = fopen(fname, "wb");
size_t ground_cnt, obj_cnt;
(...)
fprintf(file, "ground %Iu object %Iu %Iu\n", ground_cnt, obj_cnt, sizeof(size_t);
```

However, when I try to parse it back, the following format will only return the first value

```
char aux_line[4096];
size_t ground_cnt, obj_cnt, size;

file = fopen(fname, "rb"); 
fgets(aux_line, 4096, file);
sscanf(aux_line, "ground %Iu object %Iu %Iu\n", &ground_cnt, &obj_cnt, &size);
```

What could be wrong?

**Note** I am using MSVC (Visual Studio 2013) and therefore I must use the `%Iu` format specifier, as `%zu` is not supported.

Comment: @AlterMann does not work

Comment: What are the contents of the file? What are the contents of aux_line?

Comment: @DavidRoundy the aux_line string is correct ("ground 8000 object 1000 8\n"

Comment: What is `%Iu` supposed to be? I can't find it in the [MSDN specifications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdb9w69d.aspx).

Comment: @MarkRansom https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tcxf1dw6.aspx

Comment: @MarkRansom http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15610053/correct-printf-format-specifier-for-size-t-zu-or-iu

Comment: @manatttta That's for [`printf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56e442dc.aspx). [The `scanf()` specifications are different.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwwtf9ch.aspx)

Comment: @manatttta thanks. It figures that Microsoft would have multiple pages with the same information, some of it incomplete.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune indeed I change %Iu to %d (changing size_t vars to int) and it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works well with `%zd` format specifier, which as you mentioned is not supportted by Visual Studio 2013. The problems seems to be with the format specifier itself.

What you can do is either:

1. Use `unsigned long long` or `int` values with the `%llu`/`%d` specifier (depending on your requirements; it will be portable and the overhead will be minimal or none in case of `int`).
2. Use [`inttypes.h`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#inttypes.h) header file (explained under the link attached) with different format specifiers.