# define function with pointer input

Tags: c, function, pointers

I don't fully understand how to work with pointers.

Inside the function is where I need to write code to return the length of input string.

```
int mystrlen (const char *s)
{
    char *s[1000], i;
    for(i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i);
    printf("Length of string: %d, i");
    return 0;
}
```

Could you tell me how to make it work?
Thank you!!

Comment: Why have you declared `s[]` to be an array of pointers when you are already passing `s` as a pointer to `char` into the function? Also, your `printf()` call is not going to print the result you are expecting (due to a typo). And why is the `mystrlen()` function returning 0 regardless of the length of the input string? And note that the `char` variable `i` may not be able to hold the lengths of commonly expected strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `char *s[1000]`, declare `int i` instead of `char i`, and return `i` rather than 0:

- You need to remove the `s` inside the function body because it is "shadowing the variable" `s` that is a function parameter, meaning the `s` function parameter cannot be read at all.
- Changing `char i` to `int i` will likely increase the range of possible values to return.  If you pass a string with 128 characters in it, `char i` would result in returning -128 if it is a signed 8-bit type.  `int` is guaranteed to be 16-bit, allowing for strings up to 32767 characters (more than enough for most common uses of a string length function).
- You return `i` because otherwise the function is pointless; even if you print the value, you'd need a way to use the string length, and you can't do that if you don't return it from the function.

Corrected code with example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mystrlen(const char *s)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i);
    return i;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *s = "Hello world!";
    int len = mystrlen(s);
    printf("Length of string: %d\n", len);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Better than `int i` would be `size_t i`, since `size_t` is an `unsigned` integer type guaranteed to be wide enough to hold the size of any array. Also note that the Standard Library `strlen()` function returns a `size_t` value.

Comment: @DavidBowling I agree, but the explanation would detract the answer from the primary focus, especially since some implementations do not support the standard `z` length/size modifier for `printf` and friends (for example, [MSVC didn't add it until VS2013](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44055215), requiring `%Iu` up to that point) or default to C89 mode where the `z` length/size modifier wasn't even available.

Comment: Who cares about MSVC?! If C is being written, one would expect them to use a C compiler.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala It supports the C++ subset of C, and it will happily compile standard C89 code. Also, people new to the language still install it (or are required to install it) with the unfortunate expectation that it will work for all C code. Aside from that, some C compilers default to C89 mode, so they may as well be using MSVC.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using pointers, as the number says, consist in using a reference instead of the actual variable, so if you pass a reference by parameter, you are not passing the actual value of it, just an address to it!

The correct code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int mystrlen (const char *s)
{
    int i;
    for( i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; ++i);
    printf("Length of string: %d\n", i);
    return 0;

}

void main(){
    char *string = "Hello World";
    mystrlen(string);
}
```

Another thing to point out is that you're trying to declare a const variable and change it. When you declare a const variable it should not change.

Comment: How is the OP trying to change a `const` variable?

Comment: Trying to redefine the *s `const` variable?

Comment: That's [variable shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing#Lua), not changing the type or value of an existing variable. :)

Comment: Got it! Thank you @ChronoKitsune