# Do the "<" and ">" operators work correctly when size_t overflow?

Tags: c, printf, overflow, operator-keyword, size-t

I'm working on a project to update 20 year old code, and many of the issues have to do with integer overflow.  I wanted to make sure I was testing for overflow correctly, so I wrote a test program.  It's output supprised me.  Here it is:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main (void) {

   size_t largerNum,Num;

   largerNum = 12;
   Num = UINT_MAX;

   printf("largerNum = %u\nNum = %u\nNum + 1 = %u\n", largerNum    , Num, Num + 1);

   largerNum = Num + 1;

   printf("largerNum now = %u\n", largerNum);

   if(largerNum < Num ){
      printf("largerNum overflowed to %u\n", largerNum);
   }
   else {
      printf("largerNum did not overflow: %u\n", largerNum);
   }

   printf("Is (0 < UINT_MAX)?\n");

   (0 < UINT_MAX)?printf("YES\n"):printf("NO\n");

   printf("Is (largerNum < Num)?\n");

   (largerNum < Num)?printf("YES\n"):printf("NO\n");

   return 0;
}
```

And its output:

```
[afischer@susm603 /home/afischer/Fischer_Playground/overflowTest]$ main
largerNum = 12
Num = 4294967295
Num + 1 = 0
largerNum now = 0
largerNum did not overflow: 0
Is (0 < UINT_MAX)?
YES
Is (largerNum < Num)?
NO
```

I've looked at some other posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899088/uint-max-1-equals-what) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988588/is-using-unsigned-integer-overflow-good-practice) and read this [paper](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~regehr/papers/overflow12.pdf), but it has not made the output anymore clear.  Anyone see this before?

Edit: I got it to work when changing from `size_t` to `unsigned long`, which shouldn't do anything.

```
  6 int main (void) {
  7 
  8    unsigned long largerNum,Num;
  9 
 10    largerNum = 12;
 11    Num = UINT_MAX;
 12 
 13    printf("largerNum = %u\nNum = %u\nNum + 1 = %u\n", largerNum    , Num, Num + 1);
 14 
 15    largerNum = Num + 2;
 16 
 17    printf("largerNum now = %u\n", largerNum);
 18 
 19    if(largerNum < Num ){
 20       printf("largerNum overflowed to %u\n", largerNum);
 21    }
 22    else {
 23       printf("largerNum did not overflow: %u\n", largerNum);
 24    }
 25 
 26    printf("Is (0 < UINT_MAX)?\n");
 27 
 28    (0 < UINT_MAX)?printf("YES\n"):printf("NO\n");
 29 
 30    printf("Is (largerNum < Num)?\n");
 31 
 32    (largerNum < Num)?printf("YES\n"):printf("NO\n");
 33 
 34 
 35    printf("largerNum = %u\n", largerNum);
 36    printf("Num = %u\n", Num);
 37 
 38    return 0;
 39 }
```

Output:

```
[afischer@susm603 /home/afischer/Fischer_Playground/overflowTest]$ main
largerNum = 12
Num = 4294967295
Num + 1 = 0
largerNum now = 1
largerNum overflowed to 1
Is (0 < UINT_MAX)?
YES
Is (largerNum < Num)?
YES
largerNum = 1
Num = 4294967295
```

Edit2:

Upon reading some comments, I substituted 'UINT_MAX' for 'ULONG_MAX', and the ternary operators functioned correctly.  I then changed 'size_t' to 'unsigned long'. and it still works correctly.  What is odd to me is that on my machine, 'size_t', 'unsigned int', and 'unsigned long' are all the same number of bytes, and 'UINT_MAX' and 'ULONG_MAX' are the same value, yet that ternary operator would still fail despite everything being the same.  Maybe it's not the same? This upsets my understanding of C.

For those interested, the working code:

```
  6 int main (void) {
  7    /* Can be size_t or unsigned long */
  8    size_t largerNum,Num;
  9 
 10    largerNum = 12;
 11    Num = ULONG_MAX;
 12 
 13    printf("largerNum = %u\nNum = %u\nNum + 1 = %u\n", largerNum    , Num, Num + 1);
 14 
 15    largerNum = Num + 2;
 16 
 17    printf("largerNum now = %u\n", largerNum);
 18 
 19    if(largerNum < Num ){
 20       printf("largerNum overflowed to %u\n", largerNum);
 21    }
 22    else {
 23       printf("largerNum did not overflow: %u\n", largerNum);
 24    }
 25 
 26    printf("Is (0 < ULONG_MAX)?\n");
 27 
 28    (0 < ULONG_MAX)?printf("YES\n"):printf("NO\n");
 29 
 30    printf("Is (largerNum < Num)?\n");
 31 
 32    (largerNum < Num)?printf("YES\n"):printf("NO\n");
 33 
 34    
 35    printf("largerNum = %u\n", largerNum);
 36    printf("Num = %u\n", Num);
 37    
 38    return 0;
 39 }
```

Output:

```
[afischer@susm603 /home/afischer/Fischer_Playground/overflowTest]$ main
largerNum = 12
Num = 4294967295
Num + 1 = 0
largerNum now = 1
largerNum overflowed to 1
Is (0 < ULONG_MAX)?
YES
Is (largerNum < Num)?
YES
largerNum = 1
Num = 4294967295
```

Final Edit:

After reading more comments, I found that my `printf()` statements were wrong.  Thank you all for your help, and everything makes way more sense now. =D

Final code:

```
  6 int main (void) {
  7 
  8    unsigned long largerNum,Num;
  9 
 10    largerNum = 12;
 11    Num = ULONG_MAX;
 12 
 13    printf("largerNum = %zu\nNum = %zu\nNum + 1 = %zu\n", larger    Num, Num, Num + 1);
 14 
 15    largerNum = Num + 2;
 16 
 17    printf("largerNum now = %zu\n", largerNum);
 18 
 19    if(largerNum < Num ){
 20       printf("largerNum overflowed to %zu\n", largerNum);
 21    }
 22    else {
 23       printf("largerNum did not overflow: %zu\n", largerNum);
 24    }
 25 
 26    printf("Is (0 < ULONG_MAX)?\n");
 27 
 28    (0 < ULONG_MAX)?printf("YES\n"):printf("NO\n");
 29 
 30    printf("Is (largerNum < Num)?\n");
 31 
 32    (largerNum < Num)?printf("YES\n"):printf("NO\n");
 33 
 34 
 35    printf("largerNum = %zu\n", largerNum);
 36    printf("Num = %zu\n", Num);
 37 
 38    return 0;
 39 }
```

Final Output:

```
[afischer@susm603 /home/afischer/Fischer_Playground/overflowTest]$ main
largerNum = 12
Num = 18446744073709551615
Num + 1 = 0
largerNum now = 1
largerNum overflowed to 1
Is (0 < ULONG_MAX)?
YES
Is (largerNum < Num)?
YES
largerNum = 1
Num = 18446744073709551615
```

Comment: Which part surprises you exactly?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199333/how-to-detect-integer-overflow-in-c-c

Comment: isn't the type of `size_t` dependent on the machine you are running on? maybe the max of `size_t` is greater than `UINT_MAX`?

Comment: @Luchian `largerNum now = 0` and on the very next line `0 < UINT_MAX` returns false. Anyway, I cannot reproduce the result on VS2015, using the 32-bit compiler.

Comment: @Praetorian I couldnt reproduce it either

Comment: In `(0 < UINT_MAX)` does your compiler consider `0` to be `int`? If so, `(0 < 0xFFFFFFFF)` is false.

Comment: I think `size_t` is 64-bit on your platform, but you're using the wrong `printf` format specifier, and thus truncating. Since this is tagged C++ as well, use `cout` for printing, and your problems will probably go away.

Comment: @Praetorian I think you should build an answer out of this, `%u` is simply not the correct way to display `size_t`.

Comment: @Praetorian in MSVC `limits.h` it is `#define UINT_MAX 0xffffffff`

Comment: @WeatherVane Never mind what I said earlier, it doesn't matter anyway. That literal is too big to fit into an `int`, so it'll be promoted to an `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Praetorian pls ignore mine too since OP does not dispute `(0 < 0xFFFFFFFF)`

Comment: @Praetorian just got there, upvoted you: when I compiled/ran OP's code in MSVC, I got the correct result for the last test: `Is (largerNum < Num)? YES` which suggests his `size_t` is different to mine.

Comment: Making it work with 'unsigned long' shows: it is an printf issue Please fix it, better get rid of these..

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I've gone through some of these comments and incorporated some of the information into the code.  One of the things i realized is that for sake of completeness `UINT_MAX` should have been `ULONG_MAX`, but that doesn't explain why changing the original code stipit from `size_t` to `unsigned long` would allow the code to function correctly.

Comment: @DieterLücking Is there any reason why an `unsigned long` would be treated differently from `size_t`? Not disputing that it is treated differntly, just looking for a history lesson or explaination of printf's internal workings i guess.

Comment: @Praetorian I'm here! just reading and testing! =)

Comment: @Makenbaccon 32 vs. 64 bit (size_t) is the difference

Comment: @DieterLücking I updated my code to reflect proper usage of `printf()`, and huzzah! there it is, all the numbers I wasn't seeing. =D Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is your platform has a 64-bit `size_t`, and you're using the wrong format specifier to print a `size_t`, which is [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14504175/241631) and is resulting in the misleading output.

To [print `size_t`s](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1669254/241631), use `%zu` on gcc and clang, and `%Iu` on MSVC. Or forget all that and use `std::cout` to print the results.

Using `%Iu` on VS2015, the output I get on a 64-bit compiler is

```
largerNum = 12
Num = 4294967295
Num + 1 = 4294967296
largerNum now = 4294967296
largerNum did not overflow: 4294967296
Is (0 < UINT_MAX)?
YES
Is (largerNum < Num)?
NO
```

Comment: I'm going to go look up `%zu` right now.  I'm more confused why changing `size_t` to `unsigned long` would make my code work.

Comment: Is there any reason why an `unsigned long` would be treated differently from `size_t`? Not disputing that it is treated differntly, just looking for a history lesson or explaination of printf's internal workings i guess.

Comment: @Makenbaccon `unsigned long` may differ in range from `size_t`.  Same size does not mean same range - although _that_ is rare.

Comment: Disregard all of my ignorance.  I've updated the final code with those pesky `%zu` entries and huzzah! everything makes sense.  Thank you for your time. =)

Comment: @Makenbaccon Try printing the sizes of `unsigned int`, `unsigned long` and `size_t` (remember to use `%zu` to print the result of `sizeof` :)). The first two are probably 4 bytes each and the last 8.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding to @Praetorian's answer and showing a type safe implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main (void) {
   using std::size_t;
   using std::cout;

   size_t largerNum = 12;
   size_t Num = std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max();

   cout << "largerNum = " << largerNum << "\nNum = " << Num << "\nNum + 1 = " << Num + 1 << "\n";
   largerNum = Num + 1;
   cout << "largerNum now = " << largerNum << "\n";

   if(largerNum < Num ){
       cout << "largerNum overflowed to " << largerNum << "\n";
   }
   else {
       cout << "largerNum did not overflow: " << largerNum << "\n";
   }

   cout << "Is (0 < Unsigned Maximum)?\n";

   (0 < std::numeric_limits<size_t>::max())?cout << "YES\n":cout << "NO\n";

   cout << "Is (largerNum < Num)?\n";

   (largerNum < Num)?cout << "YES\n":cout << "NO\n";

   return 0;
}
```

Hence: 'printf' a not a good choice in C++, it is not type safe (although good compilers can recognize invalid format specifiers). On the other hand the iostream operators are cumbersome (for many) and are bad if an output has to be translated to different languages (eg.: gnu getline). You may browse the net for a type safe format string (eg.: boost::format)

Comment: Thank you, this will effect how I code in c++.  I originally tagged this c++, but that was a mistake. I'll have to look into boost::format. Thanks again for your help!